# .net httpclient encapsulation "one or more errors" occured

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

A problem was encountered when I was trying to encapsulate a .net http client rest helper, I just don't know where is the problem, would someone be so kind to offer a hand.
helper class below:

```
public class RestHelper
{
    private string BuildApiUriFromRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        return request.Url.ToString();
    }
    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetFromForm(NameValueCollection form)
    {
        if (form == null) return null;
        Dictionary<string, string> nameValueCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        form.AllKeys.ToList().ForEach(key =>
        {
            nameValueCollection.Add(key, form[key]);
        });
        return nameValueCollection;
    }
    public static void Get(string url, Action<string> customise)
    {
        RestMethod(url, null, customise, (httpClient, requestUrl, httpContent) =>
        {
            return httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
        });
    }
    public static void Post(string url, NameValueCollection form, Action<string> customise)
    {
        RestMethod(url, form, customise, (httpClient, requestUrl, httpContent) => { return httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, httpContent); });
    }
    public static void Put(string url, NameValueCollection form, Action<string> customise)
    {
        RestMethod(url, form, customise, (httpClient, requestUrl, httpContent) => { return httpClient.PutAsync(requestUrl, httpContent); });
    }
    public static void Delete(string url, Action<string> customise)
    {
        RestMethod(url, null, customise, (httpClient, requestUrl, httpContent) => { return httpClient.DeleteAsync(requestUrl); });
    }
    public static void RestMethod(HttpRequestBase request, Action<string> customise)
    {
        Get(request.Url.ToString(), customise);
    }
    public static void RestMethod(string url, NameValueCollection form, Action<string> customise, Func<HttpClient, string, HttpContent, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> getResponseHttpMessage)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            FormUrlEncodedContent content = null;
            if (form != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>        nameValueCollection = GetFromForm(form);
                content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueCollection);
            }
            HandleResult(client, url, content, customise, getResponseHttpMessage);
        }
    }
    private static void HandleResult(HttpClient client, string url, FormUrlEncodedContent content, Action<string> customise, Func<HttpClient, string, HttpContent, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> getResponseHttpMessage)
    {
        getResponseHttpMessage(client, url, content).ContinueWith(httpResponseMessage =>
        {
            try
            {
                httpResponseMessage.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                httpResponseMessage.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(readTask =>
                {
                    customise(readTask.Result);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                customise(ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I was testing get method when I meet with some problem, it seemed to be a delegate exception, but the compiler was not showing more exception details,
then I tried using a raw httpclient with continue-with method, and the request returned the correct result json string. Is it something about the httphandler that I was wrong about? using a pure http client may be ok? but I want it to be more slim..

Comment: test method utilizes a console program, code blow:   private const string Uri = "http://localhost:37660/api/service";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            RestHelper.Get(Uri, result =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

Comment: When you debug, which line do you encounter the error?

Comment: It was the async callback method inside. I got the result, and it did enter the callback lambada. but it seemed that I could not get the exact response. I mean that EnsureSuccessCode seemed not to be working